# Unable to make QNAP TS-2477XU-RP NFS work

Tags: nfs, nfs4, qnap

This is the product: https://www.qnap.com/en/product/ts-2477xu-rp, 32Gb Ram, AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core.

I'm trying to make it share through NFS, to no avail. I reinstalled the firmware a couple of days ago, so currently using "QTS 5.1.5.2679" version. The machine is connected through a switch as follows:

```
┌─────────────┐
│192.168.7.100│ Head (Fedora Server 38)
└──────┬──────┘
       │
┌──────▼──────┐
│192.168.7.90 │ Switch
└──────┬──────┘
       │
┌──────▼──────┐
│192.168.7.80 │ NAS (TS-2477XU-RP)
└─────────────┘
```

The NAS has no access to the internet, it's only intended to share files with "Head" machine. I have no problem to get access to the `https://192.168.7.80/` QTS admin, or to access through SSH, from the "Head" or using the "Head" as a proxy.

## Volume

I have 10 * 20Tb Hdd disks, in a Storage Pool (145Tb, Raid 6) with a single Thick Volume in it.

## NFS

I enabled NFS sharing following https://docs.qnap.com/operating-system/qts/5.1.x/qts5.1.x-ug-en-us.pdf, page 440. Currently I have it configured at "Control Panel > Network & File Services > Win/Mac/NFS/WebDAV > NFS Service" as follows:

- Enable NFS service: check
- NFS version: NFSv2 and NFSv3: check. NFSv4: check. NFSv4.1: uncheck.
- Advanced options: "Use fixed NFS service ports", "Enable manage-gids" and "Force client umask", nothing checked.

Privileges at "Control Panel > Privilege > Shared Folders", selecting "SharedFolder":

Properties:

- Folder Name: SharedFolder
- Path: /SharedFolder

Permissions, "Select permission type" set to "NFS host access".

- Access right: checked
- sync (wdelay): checked
- secure: unchecked

Allowed IP address or Domain Name: 192.168.7.0/24, sys, read/write, squash no users.

The service seems to be running OK:

Control Panel > System > Resource Monitor > Processes, showing 6 NFS Services running (rpc.statd, rpc.rquotad, rpc.mountd, rpc.idmapd, portmap, nfsd_logd), plus around 50 nfsd processes.

## Users

I've created an user with uid=1000, gid=1000 in both the Head and the NAS, with the same username (xbello), which in the NAS is in the group "Admins".

## Connection attempts

When I try to mount the Nfs from the head, these are the results. The path `mnt/STORE` exists:

```
[HEAD] # mount -t nfs 192.168.7.80:/SharedFolder /mnt/STORE -v
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Mar 21 10:24:16 2024
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=192.168.7.80,clientaddr=192.168.7.100'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Connection timed out
mount.nfs: Connection timed out for 192.168.7.80:/SharedFolder on /mnt/STORE
```

Another try using NFSv3:

```
[HEAD] # mount -t nfs 169.254.7.80:/SharedFolder /mnt/STORE -v -o nfsvers=3
 mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Mar 21 10:32:17 2024
 mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,addr=192.168.7.80'
 mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
 mount.nfs: trying 192.168.7.80 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
 mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
 mount.nfs: trying 192.168.7.80 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 42945
 (...)
 mount.nfs: mount(2): Connection timed out
 mount.nfs: Connection timed out for 192.168.7.80:/SharedFolder on /mnt/STORE
```

## My debug attempts

- Can I mount NFS from the NAS itself?

  ```
  [NAS] $ sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.7.80:/SharedFolder /share/homes/xbello/tmp
  ```

  Is able to mount the `SharedFolder` to `tmp`.
- Can I see the share from the Head?

  ```
  [HEAD] $ showmount -e 192.168.7.80
  Export list for 192.168.7.80:
  /SharedFolder 192.168.7.0/24
  ```
- What is the export config at the NAS?

  ```
  [NAS] $ cat /etc/exports
  "/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/SharedFolder" 192.168.7.0/24(sec=sys,rw,sync,wdelay,insecure,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,fsid=a-long-hash) 
  "/share/NFSv=4" *(no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,insecure,fsid=0)
  "/share/NFSv=4/SharedFolder" 192.168.7.0/24(sec=sys,rw,sync,wdelay,insecure,nohide,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,fsid=another-long-hash)
  ```
- Maybe Selinux is doing something?

  ```
  [HEAD] # setenforce 0
  [HEAD] # mount -t nfs 192.168.7.80:/SharedFolder /mnt/NAS -v
  (Eventually times out)
  ```
- Or is there a firewall blocking NFS on the NAS?

  ```
   [HEAD] # nmap -p- 192.168.7.80
   Starting Nmap 7.93 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-03-21 10:34 CET
   Nmap scan report for 192.168.7.80
   Host is up (0.00017s latency).
   Not shown: 65524 closed tcp ports (conn-refused)
   PORT      STATE SERVICE
   22/tcp    open  ssh
   111/tcp   open  rpcbind
   443/tcp   open  https
   2049/tcp  open  nfs
   8080/tcp  open  http-proxy
   33217/tcp open  unknown
   44137/tcp open  unknown
   46785/tcp open  unknown
   49743/tcp open  unknown
   59099/tcp open  unknown
   60962/tcp open  unknown

   Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 14.58 seconds
  ```

Aparently the ports 33217 and higher are used by the NFS different services, and change with each daemon restart.

- What happens if I shutdown the NFS service in the NAS?

  ```
  [NAS] $ sudo /etc/init.d/nfs stop
  Shutting down NFS services: OK

  [HEAD] # mount -t nfs 192.168.7.80:/SharedFolder /mnt/STORE -v -o nfsvers=3
  mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Mar 21 12:21:40 2024
  mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,addr=192.168.7.80'
  mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
  mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Unable to receive
  mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=17
  mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Unable to receive - Connection refused
  ```

## Workarounds

I'm very open to nuke the QNAS OS, and swap it for a TrueNAS, but as you can see in the product link, this machine doesn't have any obvious way to plug a USB and boot from it (no way to plug a screen, I don't know if it has IPMI).

I can actually share folders through SSHFS (and this is my current best bet), but another added problem is that this QNAP machine only allows SSH access to users included in the "admin" group. Even if you modify the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` entry:

```
  AllowUsers admin lower_user
```

`lower_user` still can't access through SSH, unless she is included in the "Admins" group through the QNAP admin.

Thanks.

[Edit] All IPs were changed and edited, as requested.

Comment: Have you tried with RFC 1918 IP addresses? Perhaps QNAP doesn't like link-local addresses.

Comment: @Zac64, will try. But this address is the IP that the QNAP took after installing its firmware, thus I set up all the other addresses following that.

Comment: It's Linux after all - failing to obtain an address via DHCP it falls back to zeroconf. You should either set up DHCP or use static addresses - link-local addresses are bound to change with each reboot.

Comment: I changed the IPs of all the interfaces to 192.168.7.X/24, and tried everything again. No changes. NFS mounts locally from the NAS, and a `showmount` shows the `SharedData` dir from the HEAD, but it times out. I also tried to mount it through the Fedora included cockpit webapp in the NAS, and while it seems to discover the SharedData folder, it times out when it try to mount it.

Comment: You haven't activated a service binding for NFS, have you?

Comment: At QTS interface, Control Panel > Network > Network Access > Service binding, I have "Enable service Binding" checked, and "NFS Service" bound to the adapter with the IP 192.168.7.80. All the other adapters aren't active.

Comment: i had a similar issue with a qnap, while using nfs - i had to disable nfs 2,3 and keep 4+ activated.

Comment: I just tried with only one version activated (either 2,3, or 4, or 4.1), and none of them worked. This machine is killing me.